# How to deploy rails in production mode with passenger and plesk?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have plesk 12, running RubyOnRails app on it using passenger. Everything is good.

In order to debug the app, I went to: plesk => subscriptions => my web site => Websites & Domains => WebServer Settings. I changed there Additional directives for HTTP to: RailsEnv development.

And it works fine.

Now, we want the app to work in PRODUCTION mode, so I thought that it should work by changing the Additional directives for HTTP to: RailsEnv **production**.

But it doesn't work. Also tried to delete that line entirely (maby paasenger default state is production) but it doesn't work.

Of course I restarted the server, on every attempt.

In all cases what I get is the PLESK main home page. If I try to go to one of my pages: myapp/cars/new, I get a not found error.

When I set it back to RailsEnv development - it works fine.

But I want the production env. What can I do?